# How to get the current request's full URL in Node.js Express?

Tags: node.js, express

How to get the current request's full URL in Node.js Express?

I have found the simple solution below code.

```
const app = express();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.url);    
    next();
});
```

> node -v v16.15.1
> npm -v 8.19.2

Please keep me updated if you come across another simple method. Advanced thanks for your suggestion, my code community.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @PRINCESSPARANITI you can find an answer to your question in `geeks for geeks` [How to get the full URL in ExpressJS ?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-the-full-url-in-expressjs/)